# Repeats ClassNotFoundException even after class has been put in classpath directory

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I know that classes load when they're first used in the java code. I am passing a classpath during run the java code.

Flow is: Class >> Main >> New Thread >> Call Class Constructor >> Thread Run Code >> Try to create a object of non-existing class >> Catch ClassNotFoundException >> Put non-existing class in classpath manually >> Again try to create object of that non-exisiting class >> Still throws ClassNotFoundException

Once a ClassNotFoundException occurs, I put the required .class file in classpath directory and do not want to restart my program. After ocuring ClassNotFoundException, when I start new thread from Main and follow the flow then it works fine. But does not work fine when I stays with same thread.

What to do so my program refetch classpath class files on runtime?

Comment: Hint: stackoverflow uses **markup** for formatting text. You should **not** be putting HTML tags in your questions. Instead, turn to the helpcenter to understand how you can format your input! Plus: consider putting a **minimal** viable example here. Your question sounds interesting, but I kinda dont have the time to write up the required code myself to verify your statements!

Comment: Why? If you have access to the classes at runtime why aren't they on the classpath in the first place?

Comment: @EJP because I need to receive required .class file from some remote place, and also my program needs to work on remotely received object.

Comment: So maybe you are looking for the RMI codebase feature?

Answer (score 1):

Each thread has its own class loader which can be accessed using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`. Since the first thread does not have the class in its class loader, the ClassNotFoundException is thrown. Even though you manually copy the required .class file to the classpath directory, the thread is unaware of it. This is because classes are not reloaded unless the program is restarted or a new thread is created.

You have mentioned :

> Catch ClassNotFoundException >> Put non-existing class in classpath manually

After you have caught the ClassNotFoundException, did you put the current thread to sleep until you copied the missing .class file? How did you handle this?

Comment: Exact. Your answer is explaining the reason perfectly. Now please suggest me how can I solve this problem. I have while loop that receives remote serialized object and execute some work on that object and sends back. When exception occurs, it sends error object to remote and I put missing .class file to classpath and by continuing while loop, again receive the same remote serialized object but this time it should not throw exception but it does throw.